# Azure Bot - communicate through REST APIs

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have to integrate 2 different azure bots into a single azure bot application. So thinking of integrating with the REST api. Will this approach work ?

From this links

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

I can get the access token from cloud bot. But there is no example on "sending message from client". It have examples on handling client messages from server as `Activity` object.

1. It would be better if any samples on "sending message from client to azure cloud throught REST"
2. what is different between REST and connectors.?

I believe it will be possible with `DirectLine`, but wanted to know how to do thorugh REST APIs.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you whether or not your idea will work for dealing with two separate bots without more information. If you are trying to start conversations with both bots and the sending messages to the different conversations based on some set of criteria than that should work.

The Bot Framework API can essentially split into two sections:

1. The Connector (primary) API that the bot uses to talk to users and the service.
2. The DirectLine API that you can use to talk to the bot instead of using one of the built-in connectors like Slack or Teams.

Based on your needs, the DirectLine is indeed what you are looking for. The `directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/activities` endpoint will [allow a client app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to send a message to the connected bot.